# Hide *.inc.php from website visitors

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a script myscript.inc.php which handles all urls that look like /script-blah
I accomplish this by using following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^script-(.*)$ myscript.inc.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However users could also access it this way by typing /myscript.inc.php?s=blah
I would like to prevent that. I tried

```
<Files ~ "\.inc\.php$">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</Files>
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.inc\.php
RewriteRule .* - [F,L,NS]
```

They both prevent users from viewing /myscript.inc.php?s=blah but they also cause /script-blah to return 403...

Is there a way to do this correctly?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to prevent that, as opposed to just having the script itself toss out invalid accesses?

Comment: Just my paranoid obsession with neatness :) It's not critical but would be nice to have. Putting code in the script doesn't seem like a nice way to solve the problem. But it would certainly work.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following method to protect my .inc.php files. Add the following to your .htaccess:

```
#Prevent Users From Accessing .inc.php files in .htaccess
<Files ~ ".inc.php$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try the following (a number of open source packages do this)

- place a blank `index.html` in every folder
- use this rule in .htaccess to block folder reading `Options -Indexes`
- place a line that dies scripts where a global constant isn't found

For example, here is [Kohana's](http://kohanaframework.org/) "toss out invalid accesses". It is the first line in all PHP files.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.'); ?>
```

This line basically says "if not included via index.php where SYSPATH is defined, we will abort script and show a friendly message"

Comment: I have index.php files in every directory so users will not see scripts in such way. However they can still be accessed

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect if it is a filename

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} =-f
```